An old Japanese movie about love of father and baseball
I have seen an old Japanese movie about love of father and baseball. The main actor was on the train back home (maybe? I forgot) and he thoughts about his father when he was a kid. He was not getting along with his father and they quarrel a lot. 
Actually his father loved this kid but he was just not good at expressing himself. At last father bought him a baseball bat (or maybe a pair of baseball glove? I forgot). 
The movie was probably in black and white. And his father used to wear clothes with "北野" on the collar. Maybe their family name was "北野".
This movie was released before 2000, I guess. It must be in black and white. 
The family name of the actor must be "北野". It's a movie about father's love.
"Kitano" for "北野".

